Can a Restrictive Relative Clause with an Indefinite Article be Specific?
I've been researching the topic of indefinite articles recently, and I've come across [this article][1], which states that some 'singular count nouns with specific reference in the utterance' make it so that 'instability is reduced but not eliminated, and the process of stabilization isn't completed', therefore not justifying the use of the definite article ('the').
Example
Here is one example that illustrates a noun phrase whose relative clause provides specific reference yet doesn't justify using 'the':

[1] On the table there stood a jar of sea-pinks, pressed so tightly together they looked more like a velvet pincushion, and a special shell which Kezia had given her grandmother for a pin-tray ...

Pinpointing
The article talks about 'pinpointing', which justifies the use of 'the':

... qualification with an undetached relative clause is interpreted by default as the distinctive property that justifies the pinpointing operation.

Extraction
They also talk about 'extraction' of the article, saying that even though the relative clause provides defining information in some cases, it doesn't always justify using 'a':

The quantitative/existential justification of ... extraction conveyed through ['a'] is to be found not within but outside the noun phrase, via the predication in the main clause, and the qualification conveyed in the relative clause reduces indeterminacy ... but does not eliminate it.

The idea of extraction effectively states that although the relative clause may be restrictive (not detached using a comma or a verbal pause) and highly specific, the article is determined by what's found in the main clause, not the relative clause.
In the case of Example 1, the author says this:

... the conditions for extraction are provided not in the relative clause, but in the main predication: the specific events associated to the existence of the occurrences are located in time and space via “there”.

My Thoughts
This topic is one that I've seen questioned multiple times, particularly on English Learners, yet the answers are often contradictory and vague. This is unsurprising given the lack of material on this.
With the information from this article, my question is, first and foremost, does this align with your understanding of grammar and other published material? The usual response when asked about the use of 'a' with identifying relative clauses is that the reader/listener is not able to pinpoint the reference, so does this material simply expand upon that idea, showing that aspects of the main clause (such as the verb) create uncertainty?
[1]: https://journals.openedition.org/angles/1363#:~:text=Relative%20clauses%20with%20an%20indefinite%20antecedent%20are%20problematic%2C%20and%20strangely,Rivi%C3%A8re%20and%20Rivi%C3%A8re%2022)

I think you're seriously overthinking this. It's entirely a stylistic choice which article to use in the cited context ...and a / the special shell which... The effect of using the (slightly "marked, literary") definite article (the) is simply to add "immediacy / intimacy" to the text. It implies that the reader might already be familiar with the pin-tray shell, even though that's obviously impossible in reality. This "narrative device" thereby draws the reader in, as if they were somehow part of the context being described, rather than just reading about it.

@FumbleFingers, that's a brilliant way to describe it. And yes, I'm definitely putting a lot of thought into it because that's what these forums are for, right? :)

I voted to migrate this to English Language Learners, but I'm not sure now. Maybe it should be on SO Literature - much depends on whether we see it as "learning English" or "style advice", but we only have a migration path to ELL here. I personally don't think it's an ELU question, though (it's really "matter of opinion"), but not everyone always thinks the same as me.

I thought the detail was a bit too much for Learners, and the focus on different elements of the clause is more theoretical than stylistic, in my opinion. My question is more 'do you agree with this analysis?' than anything else, so there needs to be an understanding of idiomatic usage and grammar to debate productively.

I seriously doubt many native speakers ever get explicitly taught anything about the implications of using definite / indefinite articles in such contexts, and I don't think that your "analysis" is either accurate or useful. All there is to say about this really is just what I wrote initially - you're seriously overthinking this.

In a fiction the narration can reveal a character's thought -- the thought seems to emanate from that character's mind even when it is the third-person omniscient narrator "speaking". So if you were to say "the special shell which Kezia had given her grandmother for a pin-tray", it could be taken as the character's thought, not the narrator's, with the definite article expressing that the shell is the focus of the character's thought.  There should be plenty of discussion of this technique online if you search for Henry James and "Daisy Miller".

Putting FumbleFingers' analysis into a clearer format:

[1a] On the table there stood a jar of sea-pinks, pressed so tightly
together they looked more like a velvet pincushion, and a special
shell which Kezia had given her grandmother for a pin-tray ...

The first 'a' is the usual indefinite article used with as yet non-introduced and everyday rather than renowned objects; the second 'a' parallels this.

[1b] On the table there stood a jar of sea-pinks, pressed so tightly
together they looked more like a velvet pincushion, and the special
shell which Kezia had given her grandmother for a pin-tray ...

Here, the switch to the definite article adds emphasis to the shell, highlighting it as being more significant than the jar of sea-pinks. It does not necessarily refer to a previous mention (in fact the inclusion of 'special' disfavours this reading), nor does it imply that the shell is renowned, well known to the general public.
